# How do I stop FullRowSelect from also selecting a column header

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.7.2

I looked on other posts about DataGridView SelectionMode but I did not find anyone with the same problem.

Only happens on `.NET 4.7.2`

When I select a row, the header for the column I clicked also gets selected, like this:

[image: Selected header]

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this. Give more details about how this DataGdidView is set up. You can find it in the FormName.Designer.cs file unless you also did stuff yourself manually in the FormName.cs file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following two lines of code to your constructor (the first line can also be set in the designer):

```
GridContatos.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;
GridContatos.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = GridContatos.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor;
```

Answer (score 0):

The selected answer does work 100%, but I had a few forms and also adding more as the application grows. So I created my own custom DataGridView so that I do not have to add this line to each new form.

1. Create a custom DataGridView to be used by your application.
2. In the constructor, you can handle the DataGridView's ColumnStateChanged event and reset the HeaderCell's Style to the default background value:

e.g (I actualy already had a custom grid for other reasons like search filtering):

```
public class DataGridViewCustom : DataGridView
  {
    public DataGridViewSearch() : base()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
  
      this.ColumnStateChanged += DataGridViewCustom_ColumnStateChanged;
    }
  
    private void DataGridViewCustom_ColumnStateChanged(object sender, DataGridViewColumnStateChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      DataGridView dataGridView = (DataGridView)sender;
      //Only update for full row selection mode.
      if (dataGridView.SelectionMode == DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect)
      {
        e.Column.HeaderCell.Style.SelectionBackColor = dataGridView.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor;
      }
    }
  }
```