# datagridview fullrowselect but why column still select and highlighting ? .net5

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I choose fullrowselect It's the correct choice but why is it still highlighting the header columns?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKmvZ.png)

I don't want the highlights header, normally I can't use .net framework.

Comment: post code please, thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I stop FullRowSelect from also selecting a column header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58435410/how-do-i-stop-fullrowselect-from-also-selecting-a-column-header)

Comment: @d.moncada sorry I couldn't show it, it secret in company.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.